# PHP selector - part of text dropped during post

Tags: php, forms, select, post

This is part of a php/html form -

```
echo"<form action='fly_done.php' method='post' id='fly_form'>";

/* captains name from members list*/    
    echo "<select id='captain_selector' name='cap' form='fly_form';>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $z = $row["mem"];
    echo "<option value=". $z .">$z</option>";  
    }
    echo "</select>";

full blah blah
```

It takes a members name from a database list and put it into the selector. This works fine, but when the result is posted to the next page it drops the second name ie "Newnham Bernard" becomes "Newnham". Does anyone know how to keep it complete>
Thanks. 
B

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing quotes around the `value` attribute, so your browser stops evaluating the value after the first space.
Try this:

```
echo"<form action='fly_done.php' method='post' id='fly_form'>";

/* captains name from members list*/    
    echo "<select id='captain_selector' name='cap' form='fly_form';>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $z = $row["mem"];
    echo "<option value=\"". $z ."\">$z</option>";  
    }
    echo "</select>";

full blah blah
```